# Set httpRequest proxy in android

Tags: android, proxy, httprequest

I want my android application (not my device) use a special proxy setting for all requests

Is there any way to set that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [`URLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) you can create the connexion with this :[`URL.openConnection(Proxy)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection(java.net.Proxy))

Comment: thanks but I want a setting for all my application not a single request

Comment: @HossainKhademian Singleton ?

Comment: I want to all of my app request use a proxy setting like all use "localhost" and "admin:1234"